# Is if statement necessary for empty array situation?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, shopify, liquid

I'm using Shopify Liquid.
If I don't include `{% if my_array %}` and have a code such as this:

```
{% for var in my_array %}
Do this heavy task
{% endif %}
```

does it skip the "heavy task" if **my_array** is **empty** or is it better to include the if statement (performance wise)?
Thank you.

Comment: if you add `{% if my_array.size > 0  %}` at starting of code acts as a check and if empty then it stops processing inside code, I think performance-wise this is good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, but I found [this](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/tags/iteration-tags#else) from Shopify developers documents.
According to Shopify, `{% for var in my_array %}` also acts like an if statement, which can be combined with `{% else %}` for when the array is empty. for example:

```
{% for var in my_array %}
Do this heavy task
{% else %}
<p>This array is empty</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps others searching for it too.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to check whether it is empty or not

```
{% if my_array !== blank %}
Do this heavy task
{% else %}
<p>This array is empty</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Close, but the "not equal" should be `!=` in liquid. Just modify your above snippet and your reply would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're writing it in liquid, you won't see any performance issues since the result will already be written when the page loads.